# QMessageBox::information crashes the app on macOS (ARM)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, apple-silicon

I have the 'msgtest' QtCreator project:

*msgtest.pro*

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Login success.", "You have successfully logged in!");
}
```

*mainwidnow.ui*
[image]

The important part is the `pushButton` slot `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()` in *mainwindow.cpp*:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Login success.", "You have successfully logged in!");
}
```

The problem is that when I click the button the program crashed and MacOS want me to send crash report to Apple. Why `QMessageBox::information` wont work?

I am trying to find something about my situation on the web for 2 days without success. Hope You will help me out.

My setup:
MacBook Air M2 (ARM),
MacOS Sonoma 14.0, Qt Creator 11.0.3,
Qt kit:

[image]

The debugger output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? What's the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry for not providing it. Im pretty new to qt creator. Before it I were developing in nvim and debugging with gdb. I have added the debugger screenshots to post.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of text, just post the text directly

Comment: @AlanBirtles I cant copy the output of lldb from Qt Creator, sorry.

Comment: Stacktrace indicates a problem with loading some PNG file, likely the icon. Therefore I'd lean towards faulty QT installation (try the standalone one instead of brew) or MacOS data protection services kicking in (or both). Latest OSX versions seem notorious for weird behaviour in that manner.

Comment: @alagner I installed qt stuff with https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer and everything works. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alagner mentioned, homebrew's Qt is kinda broken on apple silicon, so to solve this I have removed qt and qt-creator packages with brew and installed qt creator and libraries with https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer . It's kinda sad that I cant just type `brew install qt qt-creator` anymore to boot strap qt workflow on new Mac from command line.

BUT now, the `QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Login success.", "You have successfully logged in!");` does not break the app.

Thank you all guys!